# undefined table data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently having a lot of frustration with

```
  <?php echo $this-> table-> generate('$records'); ?>
```

which just tells me "Undefined Table data"

where in my controller I have

```
    $this-> load-> library('table');   
    $data['records']= $this-> db-> get('data'); 
    //my table name is data yes, I've loaded from this table multiple times. There is data there. 
    $this-> load-> view('site_view', $data);
```

I'm using WAMP sever and i google'd that I'm not alone with this problem. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/203194/ which is odd. I really want to stick with wamp if possible...

Does anyone have a quick example that I don't have to query from the db, and have some preset to make sure I can even show data with the generate() function? I can't get rid of that error message in any way. I get the feeling that I'm not setting up the generate function correctly..
for example...

```
   $data = array(
         array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'),
         array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small'),
         array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large'),
         array('John', 'Green', 'Medium')
         );
```

Also I cannot test it on xampp for some odd reason... I guess I'll just have to test it on my shared hosted server?...

Comment: are you sure that it should be _generate('**$records**');_

Comment: Haha. Whoops. Looks like that was the error.... wow dumb mistake on my part. I admit I'm a little sleepy right now. I should take a short nap... Thanks!

Comment: Dont work hard, reboot yourself sometimes =)

Comment: @safarov I agree, tirdness is not an alloy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove quotes `$this-> table-> generate($records);`